# Oracle - Error using columns from cte into joins

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, common-table-expression

I have the following example:

```
with qD as (select 20230101 dstart from dual)
select m.*
from qD, mfhd m
left outer join DOCHD d on d.DOCID=m.DOCOUTID and d.DOCDATE<=dstart
```

which raise the error 00904 "DSTART" invalid identifier

How can I build the statement using that condition in the join?
All the columns exposed exists in the two tables, MFHD and DOCHD

Comment: What are you trying to do here? A [mcve]  would make things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause) and explicit joins (with the `join ... on` syntax). Explicit joins have higher precedence than implicit joins, so they are evaluated first, which causes the errors you are getting. Use explicit joins consistently:

```
with qD as (select '20230101' dstart from dual)
select m.*
from qD q
cross join mfhd m --> explicit join
left join dochd d on d.docid = m.docoutid and d.docdate <= q.dstart
```

Side notes:

- In a multi-table query, it is a good practice to qualify all column names with the table they belong to
- You seem to be storing dates as numbers - that's usually not a good idea (eg: you can't easily validate such values, or perform date arithmetic). On the other hand, if column `docdate` in table `dochd` is of a `date`-like datatype, you should compare it against a literal date:

  ```
  with qD as (select date '2023-01-01' dstart from dual)
                 --  ^ literal date  ^
  ```

Comment: > "As a starter: this is invalid SQL. The literal string needs to be quoted"

Not necessarily. It could be a number type and not a string.
Depends on the type of d.DOCDATE

Comment: It's not a string, it is an integer. and the column's values are also integers. executing your qry, also raise error withe the d.DOCDATE invalid identifier.

Comment: @user3346031: the `d` alias was missing. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix legacy comma-joins with the ANSI join syntax; however, you need to put the ANSI join first and the comma-join last and cannot use `OUTER JOIN`s at the same level; but you can use `OUTER JOIN`s nested in a sub-query:

```sql
with qD as (
  select 20230101 dstart from dual
)
SELECT m.*
FROM   (
         select m.*, d.docdate
         from   mfhd m
                LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCHD d
                  ON d.DOCID = m.DOCOUTID
       ) m,
       qd
WHERE  m.DOCDATE <= qd.dstart (+);
```

However, it is better practice to just use a single join syntax:

```sql
with qD as (
  select 20230101 dstart from dual
)
select m.*
from   mfhd m
       CROSS JOIN qD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCHD d
         ON d.DOCID = m.DOCOUTID AND d.DOCDATE <= qd.dstart;
```

In this case, you are not selecting any columns from the `OUTER JOIN`ed tables so (provided `DOCHD` does not have any duplicates) then you can simplify the query to:

```sql
select *
from   mfhd
```

As all the other tables and joins are irrelevant.

Comment: The first solution raise error 25156 and gives an incorrect result; I want all the conditions to be in the left outer join, otherwise, the join turns into a strict join. The 2nd is same as the #theoa